SAML SSO integration with Spring boot and Angular using Ping Federation IDP
Simple and clear explanation. I'm facing a challenge in my SAML SSO implementation. Can you please help on it. In my case Spring boot is SP and Ping Federation is IDP server and Angular is web client. while accessing the secured resource, SAML request is generated from SP and send it to IDP server successfully. IDP server process the request and send back the response through ACS URL. Now, Where we can handle this response? is the big concern. we have tried two scenarios: 1: handle the response in SP and extract the attributes. but after that how to send those attributes to Angular login page. if we use redirect flow, multiple user are accessing the same time, which user will get access first even its a Async way. 2: if we handle the response in Angular side, Page is giving 405 error response due to ACS URL is not supported the http method(both GET and POST). Can anyone help me how to tackle this.
I'm able to send the AuthnRequest using opensaml lib to IDP server. IDP server process the request and sending the saml response.
Steps for what i did:
step1: sending the login request from angular page to SP (Spring boot).
step2: SP received the request and generate AuthnRequest and send to IDP server as a browser redirect way.
step3: IDP server popup the certificate authentication. Once user accept the certificate IDP server sending the Saml Response through ACS URL.
step4: tried two different way to handle the saml response.
created a page for handling the saml response in angular page. (Now facing the issue is, we are getting 405 not allowed http method error. while response is coming from IDP.)
created a controller in SP and unmarshell the response and extracted the attributes. Now how to send this attributes to Angular client.
